# Java Custom Cursor sometimes shows as default on MacOS

Tags: java, macos

On the following code sample, the cursor will change to whatever 32x32 image you place at "icon/cursor/" with the name "pointer-measure.png".

The problem is: on MacOS, if you keep the mouse moving in and out of the frame, sometimes the custom image is shown, and other times is the default cursor that appears. This behavior I observed only on MacOS - if I run the same code on Windows, it shows the custom cursor every time.

Anyone had the same issue? Is there a workaround for that?

```
public class JavaApplication2 {

public static final Cursor MOVE_CURSOR = getCustomCursor("pointer-measure.png", "bt-drawing", 15, 15);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame  frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(300, 300);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red));
    panel.setCursor(MOVE_CURSOR);

    frame.add(panel);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static Cursor getCustomCursor(String filename, String cursorName, int hotSpotX, int hotSpotY) {
    Toolkit defaultToolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(JavaApplication2.class.getResource("icon/cursor/" + filename));
    Dimension bestCursorSize = defaultToolkit.getBestCursorSize(icon.getIconWidth(), icon.getIconHeight());
    Point hotSpot = new Point((hotSpotX * bestCursorSize.width) / icon.getIconWidth(),
        (hotSpotY * bestCursorSize.height) / icon.getIconHeight());
    return defaultToolkit.createCustomCursor(icon.getImage(), hotSpot, cursorName);
}

}
```

Obs: I was running on MacOS Sierra and Windows 10.

Comment: I have found a bug report on OpenJDK site: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8172560. But I'm not using OpenJDK, I use oracle's Java 8.